# How to use glVertexAttrib3f with vao?

Tags: opengl, vao

I use vao and vbo to draw a quad. A vertex shader has the following input:

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos
```

I would like to use glVertexAttrib3f to set a constant pos value for the vertex shader. The following code has no effect (the quad is drawing):

```
glVertexAttrib3f(0, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: The VAO has to be bound (`glBindVertexArray(VAO);`) before `glVertexAttrib3f`

Comment: It also doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification - 10.2 Current Vertex Attribute Values](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=368&zoom=100,168,609):

> The commands in this section are used to specify current attribute values. These
> values are used by drawing commands to define the attributes transferred for a
> vertex when a vertex array defining a required attribute is not enabled [...]

Note, the current Vertex attribute values are not stated in the vertex array object.

The vertex attribute with the specified index has to be disabled:

```cpp
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
```